# Running wxPython after closing Tkinter

Tags: python, loops, events, tkinter, wxpython

We have two apps, one developed with a Tkinter interface and another built using wxPython. Both are fairly sophisticated. When finished running the Tkinter app, I would like to have the wxPython app run after selecting a button in the Tkinter app. Is there away to switch event loops so that the Tkinter app can switch to the wxPython GUI seamlessly?

While the following does work after `root.destroy` in the Tkinter app:
`os.system('python wxGUI.py')`

The final program needs to be bundled into a standalone app for multiple operating systems, so this solution would only work if I create a separate `py2app` or `py2exe` for the wxPython app and call it this way (which is not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way to accomplish this would be to put wxPython into a separate thread and just hide the Tkinter app when you want to call the wxPython app. I just whipped this example together and it seemed to work for me:

```
import Tkinter
import wxapp
import wx

from threading import Thread

########################################################################
class WxThread(Thread):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        """"""
        app = wx.App(False)
        frame = wxapp.MyFrame()
        app.MainLoop()


########################################################################
class MyApp(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title = "Tkinter App"

        self.frame = Tkinter.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        btn = Tkinter.Button(self.frame, text="Open wxPython App",
                             command=self.run_wx)
        btn.pack()

    def run_wx(self):
        self.root.withdraw()
        thread = WxThread()
        thread.join()
        self.root.deiconify()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is what I had in the `wxapp.py` module:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="wxPython App")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Show()
```

You might have to experiment a bit as one of the main issues with running two different GUI toolkits is that their main loops can interfere with each other. You may have to use the multiprocessing module instead of the threading module to get around that. I'm not really sure. But this should get you started anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. This code loads the Tkinter successfully, but when selecting the "Wx" button the program crashes on a Mac with a Tcl_ServiceModelHook: Notifier not initialized Abort trap: 6 error. I tried multiprocessing to call the wxpython module but get the following warning: This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with a Framework build of python, and only when you are
logged in on the main display of your Mac.

Comment: I don't have a Mac handy to test with. This worked fine on my Xubuntu box. I think the Framework build error is probably coming from wxPython. I think certain versions of wxPython don't work without it or something like that.